# How to make bigger Heatmap more readable

Tags: python, seaborn

corrmat is correlation dataframe with 37 columns and 37 rows

Code:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,25))
sns.heatmap(corrmat,vmax=0.8,square=True)
```

I am not able to change the rotation of labels and it is creating mess as no. of variables used for correlation matrix is more in number.

Let me know how to make below heatmap more readable

[Heatmap(37*37)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkPHR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have also done an import `matplotlib.pyplot` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You can specify the following code after you create the heatmap to set the degree of label rotation of both y and x axis.

```
plt.yticks(rotation= 0)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

You can play around with the exact number of rotation until you are happy with how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn is built on top of the matplotlib library. So, to rotate labels, you'll need to access the axis object and rotate it.

Something like this might work:

```
 for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
     tick.set_rotation(45)
```

You can similarly rotate y-axis labels and calibrate the rotation angles using the number.

Comment: Hi Shreyas, thanks for answering,but this piece of code is not working for me